# Vuejs vuedraggable, when drop the element to the last index (position) the order changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuedraggable

I'm trying to use vuedraggable to drag and drop elements from one list to another, but when I drop the element from the list to the second list at the bottom of it, the item become the before the last element not the last, attached two images to explain the issue and the code:

Image while dragging the element, still not released it
[image]

Image when dropping the element (released it)
[image]

snippet of the code

```
<b-row class="draggable-dual-list">
    <b-col cols="5" class="draggable-dual-list-source">
        <div class="list-group-wrapper">
        <perfect-scrollbar
            class="scroll scroll-always-visible"
            :options="{
            useBothWheelAxes: false,
            suppressScrollX: true
            }"
        >
            <draggable
            class="list-group"
            :list="reportTemplate.avaiableComponents"
            group="report-template-components"
            >
            <div
                class="list-group-item"
                v-for="(element, index) in reportTemplate.avaiableComponents"
                :key="index"
                @click="element.active = !element.active"
                :class="{active: element.active}"
            >
                {{element.header}}
            </div>
            </draggable>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
        </div>
    </b-col>
    <b-col cols="2" class="draggable-dual-list-buttons">
        <div>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="moveReportTemplateComponents('avaiableComponents', 'selectedComponents', 'active')"
        >
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">
            <inline-svg
                src="media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-right.svg"
            />
            </span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="moveReportTemplateComponents('selectedComponents', 'avaiableComponents', 'active')"
        >
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">
            <inline-svg
                src="media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-left.svg"
            />
            </span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="moveReportTemplateComponents('avaiableComponents', 'selectedComponents', 'all')"
        >
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">
            <inline-svg
                src="media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-right.svg"
            />
            </span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="moveReportTemplateComponents('selectedComponents', 'avaiableComponents', 'all')"
        >
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">
            <inline-svg
                src="media/svg/icons/Navigation/Angle-double-left.svg"
            />
            </span>
        </button>
        </div>
    </b-col>
    <b-col cols="5" class="draggable-dual-list-destination">
        <div class="list-group-wrapper">
        <perfect-scrollbar
            class="scroll"
            :options="{
            useBothWheelAxes: false,
            suppressScrollX: true
            }"
        >
            <draggable
            class="list-group"
            :list="reportTemplate.selectedComponents"
            group="report-template-components"
            >
            <div
                class="list-group-item"
                v-for="(element, index) in reportTemplate.selectedComponents"
                :key="index"
                @click="element.active = !element.active"
                :class="{active: element.active}"
            >
                {{element.header}}
            </div>
            </draggable>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
        </div>
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

"vue": "^2.6.11"

"vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"